# Laravel User Session Issue | Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, session, php-5.6, laravel-authorization

1. (2) users are logged in App from different Computers i.e user_1 and user_2
2. I deleted database and migrated again
3. User_2 registers again
4. User_1 got logged in (by just refreshing page) with session of user_2 with name on user_2 appearing on navbar

Answer (score 1):

This is because laravel by default uses file based sessions, so it couples user one to user id one via the session.

So when 'user 2' registers a new account, it will have an id of one, and when the 'user 1' reloads, laravel checks the session, and sees that 'user 1' has the user if of one in the session, despite it no longer being his account.

Normally this is not a problem (`migrate:fresh` rarely happens on production)

The solution would be to run `php artisan session:table` and set `SESSION_DRIVER` to `database` in `.env`

That way the sessions will be stored in the database, and thus reset if the database does.

Comment: Makes Sense . Thank You